# Can I override the HTMLFormElement.action property?

Tags: javascript

I tried to override the HTMLFormElement.action property with something like

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLFormElement.prototype, "action", { set: function(value) { alert("Hey"); }});
```

but my code is never executed when I change the action like:

```
document.forms[1].action="there";
```

Also, "action" is not shown in the HTMLFormElement prototype (before I run my code). Why?

Comment: For me a property `set action` is shown for the `HTMLFormElement` after executing the first line of code. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I mean that "action" is not shown if I type "HTMLFormElement.prototype" in a fresh debugger window, before I type the first line of code (question edited).

Comment: Yup, I see that too. But I wasn't even wondering :-) I tried that too, but also couldn't get it to work. Maybe `action` cannot be overwritten? Why do you want to set a handler for the action value at all?